# How to run docker images in google-colaboratory?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, google-colaboratory

How to run docker images in google-colaboratory ?
I tried to install docker service in google-colaboratory.

However, I got the error message about " 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?", when I executed the docker's commands.

[screen-snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URNQ7.png)

I wonder How to solve this problem?

THX

Comment: are you using `sudo` to run docker commands ? or the user has been added in docker group ? it seems you are having permission issue.

Comment: It has been the root user, and I cannot run "!sudo docker xxx" on the google colaboratory.

Comment: Install `docker.io` and run `dockerd -b none --experimental --iptables=0 --rootless`. See: [Docker is not running on Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60235353/55075).

Answer (score 5):

i think right now we can't use docker in collab, i tried instaling `sudo` and even runing de docker daemon with `dockerd` command and have no positive result.

my solution was to install all the dependencies of the image by hand like this:

> !sudo apt-get update 
> !apt-get install -y wget bzip2
> !apt-get install -y gcc perl git
> !rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
>
> !cd / 
> !mkdir anaconda 
> !cd anaconda
> !wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda2-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
> !bash Anaconda2-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
> !source ~/.bashrc
> !cd ..
> !rm -r anaconda