# Docker is not running on Colab

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory

I have tried  to install Docker on google Colab through the following ways:

(1)https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

(2)https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

(3)https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10OinT5ZNGtdLLQ9K399jlKgNgidxUbGP

I started the docker service and saw the status, but it showed 'Docker is not running'. Maybe the docker can not work on the Colab.
[image]

I feel confused and want to know the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Commands are also not working? Try to pull some images. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: when I run 'sudo docker pull', it showed 'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?'

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 16):

It's possible to run Docker in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), but with limiting functionality.

There are two methods of running Docker service, a regular one (more restrictive), and in rootless mode (`dockerd` inside [RootlessKit](https://github.com/rootless-containers/rootlesskit)).

### `dockerd`

Install by:

```
!apt-get -qq install docker.io
```

Use the following shell script:

```
%%shell
set -x
dockerd -b none --iptables=0 -l warn &
for i in $(seq 5); do [ ! -S "/var/run/docker.sock" ] && sleep 2 || break; done
docker info
docker network ls
docker pull hello-world
docker pull ubuntu
# docker build -t myimage .
docker images
kill $(jobs -p)
```

As shown above, before each `docker` command, you've to run Docker service (`dockerd`) in the background, then kill it. Unfortunately you've to run `dockerd` for each cell where you want to run your `docker` commands.

Notes on `dockerd` arguments:

- `-b none`/`--bridge none` - Disables a network bridge to avoid errors.

- `--iptables=0` - Disables addition of `iptables` rules to avoid errors.
- `-D` - Add to enable debug mode.

However in this mode running most of the containers will generate the errors related to read-only file system.

Additional notes:

- To disable cpuset support, run: `!umount -vl /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset`.

Related issue: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1124.

Here are some notepads:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Lmbkc7v7XjSWK64E3NY1cw7iJ0sF1brl
- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RVS5EngPybRZ45PQRmz56PPdz9nWStIb (without cpuset support)

---

### Rootless `dockerd`

[Rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) allows running the Docker daemon and containers as a non-root user.

To install, use the following code:

```
%%shell
useradd -md /opt/docker docker
apt-get -qq install iproute2 uidmap
sudo -Hu docker SKIP_IPTABLES=1 bash < <(curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless)
```

To run `dockerd` service, there are two methods: using a script (`dockerd-rootless.sh`) or running `rootlesskit` directly.

Here is the script which uses [`dockerd-rootless.sh`](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/contrib/dockerd-rootless.sh) to run a `hello-world` container:

```
%%writefile docker-run.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
export DOCKER_SOCK=/opt/docker/.docker/run/docker.sock
export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$DOCKER_SOCK
export PATH=/opt/docker/bin:$PATH
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/opt/docker/.docker/run
/opt/docker/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental --iptables=false --storage-driver vfs &
for i in $(seq 5); do [ ! -S "$DOCKER_SOCK" ] && sleep 2 || break; done
docker run $@
jobs -p
kill $(jobs -p)
```

To run above script, run:

```
!sudo -Hu docker bash -x docker-run.sh hello-world
```

The above may generate the following warnings:

> WARN[0000] failed to mount sysfs, falling back to read-only mount: operation not permitted

To remount some folders with write access, you can try:

```
!mount -vt sysfs sysfs /sys -o rw,remount
!mount -vt tmpfs tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup -o rw,remount
```

> [rootlesskit:child ] error: executing [[ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap] [ip link set tap0 address 02:50:00:00:00:01]]: exit status 1

The above error is related to [`dockerd-rootless.sh`](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/contrib/dockerd-rootless.sh) script which adds extra network parameters to `rootlesskit` such as:

> --net=vpnkit --mtu=1500 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=builtin

This has been reported at https://github.com/rootless-containers/rootlesskit/issues/181 (however ignored).

To workaround the above problem, we can pass our own arguments to `rootlesskit` using the following file instead:

```
%%writefile docker-run.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
export DOCKER_SOCK=/opt/docker/.docker/run/docker.sock
export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$DOCKER_SOCK
export PATH=/opt/docker/bin:$PATH
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/opt/docker/.docker/run
rootlesskit --debug --disable-host-loopback --copy-up=/etc --copy-up=/run /opt/docker/bin/dockerd -b none --experimental --iptables=false --storage-driver vfs &
for i in $(seq 5); do [ ! -S "$DOCKER_SOCK" ] && sleep 2 || break; done
docker $@
jobs -p
kill $(jobs -p)
```

Then run as:

```
!sudo -Hu docker bash docker-run.sh run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN hello-world
```

Depending on your image, this may generate the following error:

> process_linux.go:449: container init caused "join session keyring: create session key: operation not permitted": unknown.

Which could be solved by `!sysctl -w kernel.keys.maxkeys=500`, however Colab doesn't allow it. Related: [Error response from daemon: join session keyring: create session key: disk quota exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54405454/55075).

Notepad showing the above:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oRja4v-PtY6lFMJIIF79No4s3s-vbqd4

Suggested further reading:

- [Finding the minimal set of privileges for a docker container](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1456).

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue as you and apparently Docker is not supported in Google Colab according to the answers on this issue from its Github repository: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/299#issuecomment-615308778.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is an old question, but this an [old answer (2020)](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/299#issuecomment-615308778)  by a member of the Google Colaboratory team.

> this isn't possible, and we currently have no plans to support this.

Answer (score -2):

The virtualization/isolation provided by docker is available in Colab as each Colab session is an isolation by itself, if one installs the required libraries, hardware abstraction (Colab by default offers a free GPU and one can choose it during run time).....Have used conda and when I switched to dockers, there was a distinct difference in performance......Docker never had GPU memory fragmentation, but using conda (bare-metal) had the same......I have been trying single colab sessions for training in TF2 and soon will have testing and monitoring sessions(using Tensorboard) and can fully understand, whether having docker in Colab is good or not......Will come back and post my feed back soon....