# Unable to start docker in Google-Colab

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to build and run my docker image in Google Colab. I have installed docker in colab and I get the following error message "docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" even when I try to run the default hello-world container using `docker run hello-world`

Comment: Same issue as described here, where you can also find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235353/docker-is-not-running-on-colab.